# Error while executing singleton Cache Manager inside class mediator

Tags: wso2, ehcache, wso2-esb

My class mediator code is :

```
package wso2.caching;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;
import java.util.Date;
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.Element;
import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;


public class CacheMe extends AbstractMediator { 

    String data = "";
    CacheManager cacheManager;
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration;
    Element element;
    private Cache mdmCache;
    boolean firstTime=true;

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
        System.out.println(new Date() + "FirstTime = " + firstTime);
        data = String.valueOf(messageContext.getProperty("propertyarray"));
        System.out.println("data from proxy service is : " + data);
        cacheData(data);
        messageContext.setProperty("ResultData", "You got Data");
        return true;
    }

    public void cacheData(String data){
        if(firstTime){
        cacheManager  = new CacheManager();
        firstTime=false;
        }
        System.out.println(new Date() + "FirstTime = " + firstTime);
        System.out.println("Checkpoint A");
        //mdmCache = new Cache(getCacheConfiguration("mdmCache"));//test
        cacheManager.addCache("mdmCache");
        System.out.println("Checkpoint B");
        this.mdmCache = cacheManager.getCache("mdmCache");
        System.out.println("Checkpoint C");
        //this.mdmCache = mdmCache;//test
        System.out.println(new Date() + " Generating MDM Data...");
        System.out.println("mdmCache.size(): " + mdmCache.getSize());
        Element eqpElement = new Element("CacheValueKey", data);
        mdmCache.put(eqpElement);
        System.out.println("mdmCache.size(): " + mdmCache.getSize());
        }
}
```

I am calling this class mediator in my esb's sequence as finally being called in a proxy service:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="cacheImplementationSeq">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="propertyarray" expression="$body"/>
   <log level="custom">
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="PropertyData" expression="get-property('propertyarray')"/>
   </log>
   <class name="cts.falcon.data.cachable.CacheData"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ResultSet" expression="get-property('ResultData')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <header name="To" action="remove"/>
   <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <resultSetResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.cts.falcon.data.cachable/">$1</resultSetResponse>
      </format>
      <args>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('ResultSet')"/>
      </args>
   </payloadFactory>
   <send/>
</sequence>
```

When i run my proxy service from try-it for the first Time my response gets cached having a unique key (Its a UUID) and again when i run my service again my previous key is replaced by a new key and a new response value. What i am looking for is if my key is same it should update the cache and if my key is different the it should get added with a new key and my previous cache key should not get vanished? I am using ehcache1.5.0 jar to achieve this that comes with wso2 esb in plugin. Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your class mediator .Debug and find

Comment: how to debug my class mediator?